# How can I represent JSON API in a Bootstrap 4 card

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I get this output from a JSON API

```
[
    {
        "Categories": "Employment  Recruiting  Social Media",
        "Name": "teamable",
        "index": 143
    },
    {
        "Categories": "Social  Social Media  Social Network",
        "Name": "facebook",
        "index": 14
    },
]
```

Is it possible to indicate this data embedded within Bootstrap 4 card similar to below using PHP

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Why shouldn't it be possible? What have you tried?

Comment: You can extract names and show them as tags

Comment: I don't know how to get started with bootstrap for something dynamic. I generally hardcode these things. Some direction is greatly appreciate